# How to grant access to External Storage on Android?

Tags: cyanogenmod, 6.0-marshmallow, external-sd, lineageos, adoptable-storage

I am using Lineage OS 14.1 on my Samsung Galaxy Mega 5.8 (GT-i9152 ; codename : crater).

I am trying to download some apps through the APKPure App and whenever i tap the "Install" button ; i get the message

" We need to access your external storage. Please Make sure the permission is not denied"

So i was wondering on how does one grant access to EXTERNAL storage on the Android Variants from Marshmallow onwards, since they don't recognize an SD card unless it is formatted as internal ?

Please note, i do NOT want to format my SD card as internal as i risk losing all my data incase the OS malfunctions, leaving me with an encrypted SD card with important contents i might not be able to access

Please guide.

Comment: What does it show in Settings -> Apps -> your app -> Permissions?

Comment: We cannot be sure of APKPure's standard download location. If it is the external SD, it would be a mess since, from Marshmallow onwards, the app is required to ask the user for permission via a component called the **DocumentProvider**. Such changes obviously break compatibility with older apps that used to write on the external SD just fine.